# Why i'm getting error for the Microsoft.SqlServer.Server namespace?

Tags: c#

I'm writing this code:

```
string sqlConnectionString = conn1;

//string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("d:\\behzadBULK.sql");
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Microsoft.SqlServer.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

but I'm getting an error in this line

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Server = ....
```

I added the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` reference, but I get this error:

> 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

What happen? Thanks.

My error:

[image]

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @Jamel hi ,why i get error in the Microsoft.SqlServer.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server(new ServerConnection(conn)); line?

Comment: Because you are using a namespace as a class and making an object of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your namespace from `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`

Comment: Hi jamal,but i can not found the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Comment: Your sql have the library `Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll`. Search that and add it to your project.

Comment: Mostly its in **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies**. Tell me when you found it!

Comment: i found that and add the reference but so get error!

Comment: But i use the Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll

Comment: Add references to:

   -> **Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll**    -> **Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll**

          -> **Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll**

          -> **Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82351/discussion-between-jamel-and-behzad-razzaqi).

Answer (score 2):

While using visual studio 2017 & above solutions did not work for me.

Simply I recreated a new project as **SQL Server Database Project**

 and choose **SQL CLR C# User Defined Function type** 
Automatically the namespace got added without any issues.

Previously i tried all nuget packages which did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a namespace, not a class, that's why error occurred.

Use a class from `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server` namespace