# Why C# does not recognize Server() even after adding assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo"

Tags: c#, smo

The type or namespace name 'Server' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
string connetionString = @"connectionStirng"; 
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString); 
var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
```

added at the top

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```

Still giving error.
Any help appricated.

Already checked:
[Why i'm getting error for the Microsoft.SqlServer.Server namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217008/why-im-getting-error-for-the-microsoft-sqlserver-server-namespace)
[I can't add Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common to my ASP.NET MVC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879987/i-cant-add-microsoft-sqlserver-management-common-to-my-asp-net-mvc-application)

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the References in your project?

Comment: "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" - You added the using, but did you also add the assembly reference?

Comment: @Han: yes it is thr

Comment: Make sure that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll` is in the references of your project. The folder might different if you use different SQL Server. Mine is SQL Express bundled in VS 2017.

Comment: Which `Server` class are you trying to use? I can't find one in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common` namespace, so I'm not that surprised that the compiler cannot either.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : trying to implement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140422/generating-sql-code-programmatically

Comment: @Han: yes, dll exist in that folder

Comment: Those seem to be using the SMO objects from the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` namespace, E.g. [`Server`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server?view=sqlserver-2016)

Comment: try to add: using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever updated question with error image

Comment: Well now you're getting the casing wrong. It's `Server` not `server`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever :Fixed. typo after installing smo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this nuget package:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects

Then add using directive:

> using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

Now you can create Server object.

```
var server = new Server();
```

**Installing SMO**

> Beginning with SQL Server 2017 SMO is distributed as the
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects NuGet package to allow users
>   to develop applications with SMO.
>
> This is a replacement for SharedManagementObjects.msi, which was
>   previously released as part of the SQL Feature Pack for each release
>   of SQL Server. Applications that use SMO should be updated to use the
>   NuGet package instead and will be responsible for ensuring the
>   binaries are installed with the application being developed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: It is already added to references and exists in folder you specified. still getting error

Comment: cant install that because of NuGet version required 2.12 but i can update NuGet because of VS 2012. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384885/how-to-upgrade-nuget-with-visual-studio-express-2012

Comment: @SureshKamrushi I saw your screenshot. You wrote `new server(...)`. It should be `new Server(...)`. C# is case sensitive.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi It would've been solved quicker if you had posted the screenshot earlier.

Comment: `using` *directive*, not `using` *statement*. C# has two features that both use the `using` keyword. Using the name of one to refer to the other doesn't aid communication.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, my mistake. I was working with VB.Net earlier. I posted Import statement in my earlier edit. Then changed Import into using, I forgot to change the statement into directive.

Comment: It solved because of installation of "Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects". typo is because i trying it with different cases.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Han, Please check the assembly reference path and make sure that the file is there at the referenced location. I had faced similar problem, this was working on the Development environment but error on test server. The reason was the SQL Server Management studio was not installed on the Test server. So i copied the required Assemblies from dev machine to bin folder of the application on test server and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding a reference to:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.dac.dll
```

If cant find the dll, then need to install SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools).